# Deprecated Chrome Extension HTML Notification

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it not allowed that using html as chrome extension notification never? Here is chrome developers say deprecated: https://plus.google.com/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/V8xpT9GgMtT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is indeed deprecated and no longer supported since Chrome 28.

It is encouraged to use the new [chrome.notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) API that is properly supported by the browser and the new notification center.